# loop through cell a looking for match within col b

Tags: excel, concatenation, match, offset, vba

Loop through a column worksheet1 a2:a and if theres match in worksheet2 column a2:a then offset found within worksheet1 b2:b if found else not found. I have mashed up some code but might have confused myself. I'm looking for clarity on my answer.

```
  Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim lookupArray As Variant
Dim lookupVal As Variant
Dim matchResult As Variant
Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim e1 As Integer
Dim e2 As Integer

    r1 = r1.Range("A2:A").Cells
    r2 = r2.Range("B2:B").Cells

    e1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select
    e2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            For rowIndex = r1 To e1
            Set lookupVal = Range(r2 & rowIndex)

            matchResult = Application.match(lookupVal, r1, 0)

            If r1.cell(i, 1).Value = r2.cell(i, 1).Value And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                  r1(i, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value "Found"
                  Else
                  r1(i, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value "NotFound"
                  End If
                'copy found cells in sheet 3
            Next rowIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

**First approach** (faster, simplier and shorter):

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long

    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
            'change Sheet2 to suit
            .Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,'Sheet2'!A:A,0)),""NotFound"", ""Found"")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

**Second approach:**

```
Sub test2()
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set r1 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    End With

    'change Sheet2 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set r2 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    End With

    For Each cell In r1
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell, r2, 0)) Then
            cell.Offset(, 1) = "NotFound"
        Else
            cell.Offset(, 1) = "Found"
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```